# Generate expressjs routes from an array of strings?

Tags: express

Is it possible to generate a list of routes from an array of strings?

For example, I have this list:

```
const routes = ["/test","/test2","/test3"];
```

and I want to generate these routes:

```
const Routes = app => {
    app.post("/test", apiCall);
    app.post("/test2", apiCall);
    app.post("/test3", apiCall);
    
};
export default Routes;
```

Then `Routes` is called in a different file like this:

```
Routes(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same `apiCall` for all these routes, you can simply write

```js
app.post(["/test","/test2","/test3"], apiCall);
```

as explained in [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples). So no need to generate anything.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!